# XmlTextReader читает не все строки в файле

Tags: c#, xml

У меня есть XML-файл, и я хочу прочитать все строки с помощью инструментов класса XmlTextReader. Ниже приведен пример файла xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSigns>
  <CodeSign Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>AAA</Title>
      <Shortcut>AAA</Shortcut>
      <Description>AAA</Description>
      <Author>Viva</Author>
      <LoadTypes>
        <LoadType>Expansion</LoadType>
      </LoadTypes>
    </Header>
    <Sign>
      <Declarations />
      <Code Language="SQL Server" Kind="SQL Server"><![CDATA[SELECT TOP 100 [Id]
       ,[TotalSeconds]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [Parameters] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [Parameters]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [Query] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [Query]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [StackTrace] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [StackTrace]
       ,[CreateDate]
       ,[MachineName]
       ,[UserName]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [Exception] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [Exception]
       ,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [InnerException] + ']]]]><![CDATA[>' AS XML) as [InnerException]
       ,[CommandType]
       FROM [QMaster].[dbo].[LogSlowQueries]
       where CreateDate > CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
       order by totalseconds desc]]>
      </Code>
    </Sign>
  </CodeSign>
</CodeSigns>
```

Нам нужен элемент, чтобы прочитать все, что он включает. Остальные элементы для нас не важны, но с этим есть проблемы, потому что вместо трех были прочитаны только три строки.
Код C #, используемый для чтения этого файла, приведен ниже:

```
public void Load(string path) {

  filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
  try {
    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path)) {
      while (reader.Read()) {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) {
          switch (reader.Name) {
            case "Title":
              title = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;
            case "ToolTip":
              tooltip = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;
            case "Description":
              description = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;
            case "Author":
              author = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;                
            **case "Code":
              language = reader.GetAttribute("Language");
              code = ReadProperty(reader);
              break;**                
          }
        }
      }
    }       
  }
  catch (XmlException) {
  }
}





private string ReadProperty(XmlReader reader) {

  if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
    return string.Empty;

  reader.Read();
  return reader.Value;
}
```

Нам нужно получить все строки из XmlNodeType.Element с именем «Code». Это должно быть прочитано все со всеми строками в этом. Однако мы получаем в reader.Value только три строки на картинке:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Большое спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, поговорим о форматировании.

Если xml отформатирован именно так, как показано в вопросе:

```
<Code Language="SQL Server" Kind="SQL Server"><![CDATA[SELECT TOP 100 [Id]
```

т. е. содержимое элемента `Code` начинается в этой же строке, тогда результат будет как у вас.

Однако, если форматирование будет таким:

```
<Code Language="SQL Server" Kind="SQL Server">
  <![CDATA[SELECT TOP 100 [Id]
```

т. е. содержимое начинается со следующей строки, то ваш код вернёт строку, состоящую из пробелов. А именно такой формат получился, когда я вставил ваш xml в редактор Visual Studio (Студия сама его отформатировала).

Вы обязаны проверять в методе `ReadProperty`, до какого узла дошли, а не просто слепо полагаться на жёстко-заданный формат. Потому что в соответствии со стандартом, xml имеет право быть отформатированным как угодно.

**Свойство `reader.Value` возвращает содержимое текущего узла. Этим узлом может быть не только `Element`, как вероятно вы ожидали, но и `CDATA`, и `Whitespace`. Соответственно,  возвращается либо содержимое первого блока `CDATA` (три строки текста), либо пробельная строка.**

---

Во-вторых, блоки `CDATA` не могут быть вложенными. Посмотрите, как их подсвечивает xml-редактор Visual Studio:

[image]

По-хорошему каждый из этих блоков нужно закрывать скобкой `]]>` перед началом следующего. Или, что проще и разумнее (на мой взгляд), оставить один-единственный блок `CDATA`.

---

Ваш метод `ReadProperty` можно заменить одной строкой:

```
reader.ReadElementContentAsString()
```

При этом будет прочитано всё содержимое элемента `Code` как одно целое. При этом текст будет извлечён из `CDATA`. Но только из тех блоков, которые парсер распознает как самостоятельные (не вложенные)! См. выше картинку.

Что делать с оставшимися кусками блоков `CDATA`? Проблему нужно решать уровнем выше: при записи/создании xml.

Возможно, вас устроит чтение без извлечения из блоков `CDATA`. Для этого используйте

```
var code = reader.ReadInnerXml();
```

---

Напоследок замечу, что класс [XmlRextReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.110).aspx) считается устаревшим, как и написано в документации.

Поэтому я бы заменил строку

```
using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path))
```

на следующую

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
```

Но это соверщенно не важно.

Comment: Все с вложенностью CDATA в порядке! У него просто внутри CDATA записан SQL-запрос который формирует CDATA на выходе :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov - хах, о таком я и не подумал.

Comment: К сожалению не получилось

Comment: @RomanIeromenko - очень информативно... Что именно не получилось? Обновил ответ. См. `ReadInnerXml`.

Comment: Не могу понять если честно почему оно считало только                                                                 "SELECT TOP 100 [Id]\r\n,[TotalSeconds]\r\n,CAST('<![CDATA[' + [Parameters] + ']]"

Comment: @RomanIeromenko - я выделил суть в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено, все работает:

```
private string ReadProperty(XmlReader reader) {

  if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
    return string.Empty;
  reader.Read();
  var st1 = reader.Value;
  while (reader.Read()) {
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
      st1 += reader.Value;
  }

  return st1;
}
```

Comment: Зачем всё это? Одна строка `ReadElementContentAsString()`, которую я привёл в своём ответе, даёт тот же самый результат.

Comment: Проследим цепочку вызовов методов: [ReadElementContentAsString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,bbfb6cf079209f95) > [ReadContentAsString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,9ed7eeae9fe5864a) > [InternalReadContentAsString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs,bc32f47f28ca622a). Там мы видим код, примерно соответствующий вашему: читаются все вложенные узлы и их содержимое объединяется.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь